# How to filter a listview for CustomAdapter

Tags: android

I'am trying to do a filter operation for my ListView. Just am getting group of five data from the server and am displaying the five data in the ListView. So i have 5 different data in my list. I want to do filter based on the single data. If am having only one data then i can just use this code ProjectEventFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);. Here my doubt is how do i custom the getFilter method in my CustomEventAdapter.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_event, container, false);
    mlist=new ArrayList<Meeting>();
    cts=CalEvent.getCalEventById(proj1.p_id);
    lv=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.eventlist);
    Button btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button11);
    context = rootView.getContext();
    meeting = new Meeting();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View vie)
        {
            NewEventactivity dialog = new NewEventactivity(proj1);
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "fragmentDialog");
        }
    });

    EditText inputSearch = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.eventFilter);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {    
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
            // When user changed the Text
            ProjectEventFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            //dialog = MeetingFragment.newInstance(position);
            dialog = new MeetingFragment(proj1);
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "fragmentDialog");
            //dialog.getDialog().setTitle("Update Event");
            event = new CalEvent();
            event = cts.get(position);
        }
    });

    settingAdapter();
    return rootView;
}

public static void settingAdapter()
{
    adapter=new CustomEventAdapter(context,cts);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);  
}
```

Please do help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using this component:

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidFilterableList

It allows you to use dynamic filters, to filter by a field of an Object etc.

It also has a sample implementation, a use case which shows you how easy it would be.

I think you won't have to change your code a lot, only implements two interfaces and fill the methods.

If you don't want to change your implementation, you also can compare your code with the code in the sample since it's working.

I hope this helps you!! ;)